# Plotting root locus - how to display 'k' values on the curve?

Tags: plotting, functions, tooltip

I'm trying to plot the root locus for the function below. Is there any way to make it display the value of 'k' when I move the cursor along the curve, similar to a tooltip?

```
RootLocusPlot[k/((s + 10) (s - 4)), {k, 0, 80}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

RootLocusPlot[k/((s + 10) (s - 4))
 , {k, 0, 80}
 , PlotStyle -> Thick
 , LabelStyle -> Directive[Gray, Small]
 , PoleZeroMarkers -> {Style["x", 16, Black], 
   Style["\[FilledCircle]", Red, 6], "", 
   "ParameterValues" -> {Range[10, 80, 10]}}
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

RootLocusPlot[k/((s + 10) (s - 4)), {k, 0, 80},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, k}, ColorData["Rainbow"][k]],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 80}},
   LegendLabel -> Style["k", 14]]]
```

[image]